# Ubuntu Software Center 11.10

Tags: 11.10, software-center

I have installed UBUNTU 11.10 64 bit version. I have setup the network connectivity. I want to use software center to install QEMU Launcher. However when I search for it in software center, I do NOT see the "INSTALL" button on the far right. I saw this in the 32 bit version. Is something missing here ?

Thanks.

Guest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open terminal from your dash and type in this command:

```
sudo apt-get install qemu
```

And that should do it